# mypy type checking with decorators

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, typechecking, static-typing, mypy

I have something like following:

In myfile.py:

```
from file1 import REQ
@has_request_variable
def fun(request, REQ(validator=check_int))
   /* body */
```

In file1.py

```
class REQ(object):
    def __init__(self, validator=None):
        self.validator = validator

def has_request_variables(view_func):
       /* body */
       # Below I am calling the validator function to check
       error = param.validator(var_name, val)
```

Now I would like to annotate fun functions using mypy, I have done in the following way and it worked but It is not ideal, As in fun I know 
message is of type int so we should annotate the argument with something like int... How can I achieve it using mypy.

```
from file1 import REQ
@has_request_variable
def fun(request, message=REQ(validator=check_int))
    # type(Any, REQ) -> Any
    msg = message # type: int
   /* body */
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, mypy is not directly related with type annotations. You can use mypy without annotating your code, because mypy is a program that uses type inference (and type annotations, if present) to typecheck your code. Also, you can use type annotations without mypy - for many useful purposes like documentation, code readability, etc.

Secondly, mypy is a static type checker. Your program is not being ran as the types are checked, so there is no point of trying doing runtime type checking with mypy (that's kinda what I see in your code in the question).

So, if you want static type checking, use **annotations**. But, if you want type checking at runtime, you can e.g. use **assertions**. Or you can use them both...

#### type annotatations (for static type checking with mypy):

According to [the PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/), type annotations let you go from the following code:

```
def print_many(what, how_many=10):
    long_what = how_many * what
    print(long_what)
```

To this, where you have the function parameters, return type, and also any local variable annotated:

```
def print_many(what: str, how_many: int=10) -> None:
    long_what = how_many * what # type: str
    print(long_what)
```

For your specific use case, if you know that `message` is of type `int`, then: `def fun(request, message: int)` would do the job.

You can just run mypy on an annotated code, and get results, but your code will be only type-checked, it will not be executed. So default values of parameters, such as `REQ(validator=check_int)` are completely ignored by mypy.

Please bear in mind that even if the PEP 0484 and `typing` module are an official part of Python 3.5, mypy is a separate project, which is working quite well already in many cases, but is still in development.

### assertions for runtime type checking:

```
def fun(request, message: int):
    assert isinstance(message, int)
    # function body
```

such assertion is ignored by mypy, but it will be checked when your function is executed.